# .NET HttpRequest from 1.1 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

We have to ASP.NET applications, one in 1.1 and one in 3.5.  In order to log our errors in the same location we are going to create a WebService that the 1.1 app can call.  If I include an HttpRequest as one of the parameters to the webservice, will there be a versioning problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be other problem - HttpRequest isn't marked as serializable, nor is MarshalByRefObj.